# How to set min max user input in angular 2 material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
 <mat-form-field class="Custom">
 <input matInput placeholder="Enter Custom Value" [(ngModel)]="Value" 
(keypress)="numberOnly($event)" min="0" max="10">
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
  numberOnly(event): boolean {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;

  }
```

How do I set min and max user input here? I have gone through this link (custom input): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-number-input?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

I'm trying put the same code as here, but it's not working. Is there anything else I can put here?

[image: User input]

Comment: You are missing to add type for the input. `type ="number"

Comment: @MaihanNijat please gone through my image which i just added here ! i made changes as per your answer!

Comment: @JustTeachMe Have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jebi4w

Comment: @PrashantPimpale you are my Hero! Thanks Sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any typescript logic here. Just make your field of type number:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" ...>
```

and the browser will care for the input for you.

Comment: yes you are right! but i can able to insert value more than 10!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale please gone through my image which i just added here ! i made changes as per your answer!

Comment: `min` and `max` do not restrict you in typing, they set your input to be valid or not. Please refer to https://angular.io/guide/form-validation . If you want to restrict the user input then you need to use some of the mask libraries out there

Comment: is there any way other than form validation that i can restrict the input man max values!

Comment: *If you want to restrict the user input then you need to use some of the mask libraries out there*. https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+input+mask . Asking for other libraries is off-topic on SO, that's why I will not advertise any

Comment: Handle keydown event and see what's input value. Reset the input value (via Model) if it is beyond your range

Comment: This is actually not between 1 and 10. but 10 characters. really dont know why they did it this way. since the input type is a number, the min and max should be understandable that it is between 1 and 100. but 1 to 100 characters

Answer (score 0):

1- You will need to specify min and max in the input tag that has the type number,

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" ...>
```

2- But also you need  to restrict typing.

2.a- you can add form validation. eg:

```
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
name: new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4),
  forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
]),
alterEgo: new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
power: new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
```

});

2.b- you can use key and mouse events to return the old value if the new value is not valid (usable in case you are dynamically programming and you do not define the forms in ts)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" onkeydown="return ((event.keyCode === 8) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.target.value+Number(event.key) < 10))" />
```

this limits entry of non numeric values and disallows if the entered value becomes greater than the specified limit(10 in case).